# Unable to access file via MS Graph API, but works via Graph Explorer

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api

An excel file is shared from User A's Onedrive (personal folder, business OneDrive) to user B.
I can access it via regular means as user B (via link etc.)

If I run this call in MS Graph Explorer it works as expected for both users:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/5fb16e7a-e5a5-47f6-91b1-e4613327c13b/drive/root:/Shared/demo.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='A1:B4')?$select=text`

This returns the same for both user A and B:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#workbookRange",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.workbookRange",
    "@odata.id": "/users('5fb16e7a-e5a5-47f6-91b1-e4613327c13b')/drive/root/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B096996EB-0C8C-4BA4-8C96-DEE0AE8C5B97%7D%27)/range(address=%27A1:B4%27)",
    "text": [
        [
            "Column1",
```

... etc

**I have written an Angular app**, registered it and use it to access the Excel file (and users Calendar).
But when I run the app as User B, I get this response:

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "code": "itemNotFound",
  "message": "The resource could not be found.",
  "requestId": "26d9fb06-99eb-4e2a-8dae-7a42012de4b9",
  "date": "2020-07-27T10:10:58.000Z",
  "body": "{\"code\":\"itemNotFound\",\"message\":\"The resource could not be found.\",\"innerError\":{\"date\":\"2020-07-27T12:10:58\",\"request-id\":\"26d9fb06-99eb-4e2a-8dae-7a42012de4b9\"}}"
}
```

Console says:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

The app works for User A. Also the Calendar access code work for both A and B.

I have tried a lot of different things - but I cannot see what is wrong!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I made further tests and found that the problem was due to a access rights.
User A, sharing the file, had all privileges being the owner, also from the Graph API.

User B however, only had **file.read** (which I considered the proper one given that a file access was asked for). It turns out it also needed **sites.read** in order to be able to access the "sharepoint site" based onedrive file storage. **So with that added it works fine also for user B!** Hopefully this experience may be of use to someone else too.